# How to get a string between two strings with line breaks using RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of text that has multiple linebreaks. I want to get some of the text inbetween it. How would I do this?

```
\w+\*\w+\*1000018220\*\n.+\n.+\n\w+\*\w+\*(\d+\.\d+)
```

I tried this, but this just goes line by line and i'm unsure of how to get between two tags that have linebreaks.

```
This is how the string looks
TEXT*TEXT*1000018220*
TEXT*TEXT*TEXT1419*
TEXT*TEXT*KH005*
QTY*QD*123.45*KH
MEA**MU*12345.6*KH***22
TEXT*150****TEXT*201900000000
TEXT*151****TEXT*201900000000
QTY*QD*123.45*KH
QTY*QD*123.45*KH
QTY*QD*0.00*KH
QTY*QD*123.45*KH
QTY*QD*0.00*KH
TEXT*TEXT*1000018220*
```

I want to get the values of the lines with the QTYQD###.##KH from between the 1000018220 headers. 
The result would return this

```
123.45
123.45
123.45
0.00
123.45
0.00
```

Comment: `flags=re.DOTALL` probably

Comment: Can't you use `re.findall(r'QTYQD([\d.]+)KH', text)` or - if the asterisks are really there  - ``re.findall(r'QTY\*QD\*([\d.]+)\*KH', text)``?